# Defining shorthand object props on Vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-props

I'm creating a Vue component library, and I'm having some issues defining properties.

Right now, on a component I have the following setup:

```
    <a-div
      :classes="{ default: '', sm: '', md: '' }"
      :colors="{ dark: '', light: '' }"
    ></a-div>
```

Where you define classes depending on the viewport, and colors depending on the current theme.

This is working fine, but I was wondering if there is an easier way (more developer friendly) to define object props. Something like this:

```
<a-div
  classes.default="'col-12'"
  classes.md="'col-6'"
  classes.lg="'col-2'"
  colors.dark="'white'"
  colors.light="'black'"
></a-div>
```

Or perhaps some way of customize props so that the component accepts any prop that the developer previously defined. Something like this:

```
  <a-div
    dark="white"
    light="black"
    randomTheme="green"
  ></a-div>
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . It's unclear what exactly the result that you need to achieve with this code. You can call props whatever you want, and you can use a mixin to reuse a list of props between comps. "some way of customize props" - as for CSS classes, custom directive can be used

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to pass whole object as `:classes` and `:colors` to the child component instead of passing as a separate property for each `color` and `layout` and I think you are already doing that correctly.

Live Demo **:**

```js
Vue.component('aDiv', {
  props: ['classes', 'colors'],
  template: `<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div :class="classes.sm" :style="{'color': colors.dark}">
      <p>
        This is a rectangle box using col-sm-4
      </p>
    </div>   
    <div :class="classes.sm" :style="{'color': colors.light}">
      <p>
        This is a rectangle box using col-sm-4
      </p>
    </div>
    <div :class="classes.sm" :style="{'color': colors.dark}">
      <p>
        This is a rectangle box using col-sm-4
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>`
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    layoutClasses: {
        default: 'col-lg-12',
      md: 'col-md-6',
      sm: 'col-sm-4'
    },
    colors: {
        dark: 'gray',
      light: 'green'
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<div id="app">
  <a-div 
         :classes="layoutClasses"
         :colors="colors">
  </a-div>
</div>
```